# It doesn't return the decrypted text, and it only returned the encrypted text

Tags: python, encryption

my program doesn't come back decrypted.
why?
please help
I seem to return the encrypted version of y
i've tried moving the return command around, but the result was the same.
does anyone know what's wrong?

```
def translate(x):
    count = 0
    while count < 1000:

        y.replace("quebrqerubfq92983rgh", "A")
        y.replace("837bfv8g24gh2783", "C")
        y.replace("9q37f93724f9732f", "E")
        y.replace("eqvrgb8rgbb452", "G")
        y.replace("1974f17934hf7h", "I")
        y.replace("1973f9734fbviu3", "K")
        y.replace("urhg9327hg9283g", "M")
        y.replace("18374f19374h983h", "O")
        y.replace("94fh93184hf91834f", "Q")
        y.replace("9rugueirgquierg", "S")
        y.replace("294uv94ugh293ugh928", "U")
        y.replace("29gh3i1fb94h9834h", "W")
        y.replace("193fh18934hfhb", "Y")
        y.replace("q9eurfuerhg93458htg", "B")
        y.replace("feugb2er9gh923gh", "D")
        y.replace("3ourv9u3rv93uv", "F")
        y.replace("v19u3rf9831hf89134h", "H")
        y.replace("913ufh9183hf91834", "J")
        y.replace("31uhf91384hf9834f", "L")
        y.replace("319fuh19hgf91834", "N")
        y.replace("fu3bf91u34bf1u34f", "P")
        y.replace("8134f87134fg13", "R")
        y.replace("f319u4f319u4hf3491", "T")
        y.replace("vq3yrbqbfuf", "V")
        y.replace("jirfbqiweufwqr440", "X")
        y.replace("qiuefqweurewiub", "Z")
        count = count + 1
    return y

x = input("")
import os
for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk("g:"):
    for subfolder in subfolders:
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename == x:
                x = open(x, "r")
                y = x.read()
result = translate(x)
print(result)
```

Comment: 1. You're passing `x` into the function but use `y`…!? 2. `str.replace` doesn't modify the string *in place*! It ***returns*** a new string.

Comment: Also, some kind of mapping is more appropriate than multiple `.replace()`. Think about a dictionary.

Comment: Why have 26 lines of code instead of 1 loop?

Answer (score 1):

`y.replace(...)` returns a new string - it doesn't work in place, since strings are immutable. Try `y = y.replace(...)`.

Comment: Also, the way you seem to be invoking it, `translate()` will only be invoked once, with the last file you've found, as an open file object rather than a string.

Comment: @Austin Yup, but this fixes the symptom the OP mentioned. They may need to fix the other thing too, but I suspect that's broken example code, not the real thing, otherwise they wouldn't have found the problem!

Answer (score 0):

That because u have some lowercase caracters in some lines of your file contect, or/and may a digits .

i think , you must to convert every lower string to upperc string for every line of your file content,  using the function upper() .

you can replace `y = x.read()` by :

```
y = x.read().upper()
```

however , @bunner is rigth , u must change `y.replace(..)` by :

`y = y.replace(..)` .

Comment: The obscure substitution cipher that OP is using seems to assume that the file to be decrypted consists of all lower case letters (otherwise there wouldn't be a unique decryption). Your suggestion would just make it impossible to decrypt.

Comment: I think , He work only with uppercases and i saw that  in his code, so , i just suggest him  to take a look on the different  cases size ( lower / upper ) using .upper() ,